# How do I click a checkbox if its not already, in BROWSER library of ROBOT FRAMEWORK?

Tags: automation, robotframework, built-in, browser-automation

I want to click a input checkbox if its not already checked but if its checked leave it and dont do anything.

I looked into documentation but didn't find answers. Tried to ask ChatGPT but it gave undefined keywords and gave some code in JavaScript which I cant use. I am using Browser library of Robot Framework. Looked into builtin library as well, didnt know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You may try with Selenium library for RF.

There is a keyword called "Checkbox Should Be Selected"
https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Checkbox%20Should%20Be%20Selected

It returns a bool value depending if checkbox is selected or not. As an argument to the keyword you should pass the locator of the checkbox.

```
${isSelected} =    Run Keyword And Return Status    Checkbox Should Be Selected   checkbox_locator
```

Later, you can simply continue with "IF" statement depending on the bool state of isSelected variable.